# Не удается запуск скрипта Python как службы на сервере Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, vps, telethon

Коллеги, подскажите может кто сталкивался. У меня есть скрипт на Pyhton для работы с API Telegram. При его запуске необходимо ввести пароль, который приходит в мою учетку Telegram (в работе скрипта используется доступ к моей учетной записи Telegram). При запуске скрипта через терминал на VPS Ubuntu все работает исправно. Но я не могу запустить его как service, чтобы он работал автономно. При попытке запуска службы с этим скриптом через терминал, получаю сообщение:

```
ldparcerchats-tg.service - ldparcerchatstg
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ldparcerchats-tg.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-12-28 16:01:16 MSK; 4s ago
    Process: 26178 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /root/myprojects/LD/parcerchats/parcer_chats_LD.py (code=exited, status=1>
   Main PID: 26178 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 28 16:01:16 2342271-ki10166.twc1.net systemd[1]: ldparcerchats-tg.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status>
Dec 28 16:01:16 2342271-ki10166.twc1.net systemd[1]: ldparcerchats-tg.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 28 16:01:16 2342271-ki10166.twc1.net systemd[1]: ldparcerchats-tg.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter i>
Dec 28 16:01:16 2342271-ki10166.twc1.net systemd[1]: Stopped ldparcerchatstg.
Dec 28 16:01:16 2342271-ki10166.twc1.net systemd[1]: ldparcerchats-tg.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 28 16:01:16 2342271-ki10166.twc1.net systemd[1]: ldparcerchats-tg.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 28 16:01:16 2342271-ki10166.twc1.net systemd[1]: Failed to start ldparcerchatstg.
```

Подскажите, это вообще возможно запустить такой скрипт, как службу?

Comment: Я может чё не понимаю, но для прог и апи телеги - вроде токены генерятся. Разве нет? При чём тут логин/пасс?

Comment: Токены генертся, да, но чтобы войти в учетную запись ТГ через API, нужно вводить пароль, который в телеграм приходит.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй выставить [WorkingDirectory](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/systemd.exec.5.html#:%7E:text=a%20%22..%22%20%20path%20component.-,WorkingDirectory%3D,-Takes%20a%20directory)
Возможно питон не вилит откудп импортровать другие файлы.